# How to wrap a string using element from the list using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a list of producers:

```
<ul>
    <li>Name 1</li>
    <li>Other name</li>
    <li>Next producer</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Somethingelse</li>
</ul>
```

In another place I want to wrap the above name using `<span> </span>`. The script is supposed to give the following effect:

Replace:

```
<p>Name 1 details of the name</p>
```

on:

```
<p><span>Name 1</span> details of the name</p>
```

The code I'm using looks like this:

```
var prodName = [];
$("ul li").each(function() { prodName.push($(this).text()); });     

$( "p" ).each(function () {
    $(this).html(function(_,html) {
        var reg = new RegExp('('+prodName.join('|')+')','gi');
        return html.replace(reg, '<span>$1</span>', html);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Everything works fine until there are elements on the list that starts exactly from the same characters: *Something* and *Something**else*** gives the effect:

it turns:

```
<p>Somethingelse details of the name</p>
```

to

```
<p><span>Something</span>else details of the name</p>
```

instead of

```
<p><span>Somethingelse</span> details of the name</p>
```

How can I eliminate this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$( "p" ).each(function () {
    $(this).html(function(_,html) {
        var reg = new RegExp('('+prodName.join('|')+')\\s','gi'); // \\s at the end of your regex
        return html.replace(reg, '<span>$1</span> ', html);
    });
});
```